# WSO2 ESB service startup causes error 1067

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

When I try to start WSO2 ESB as a Windows service, I get the error

> Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

This is happening on a Windows Vista box and a Windows Server 2008 box. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Examine error log (start eventvwr.msc). There should be more details about the error there.